# How to find the plane that contain certain two points?

Tags: linear-algebra, plane-geometry

How to find the equation of the plane containing $P(2,-1,1)$ and $Q(1,0,0)$?
But the answer says $ax+by+(b-a)z=a$; $a$ and $b$ not both $0$.  I don't quite get the process.

Comment: there are infinitely many planes containing two given points.

Comment: There are infinite many planes which contain these two points. Please check the wording of your question and for missing information.

Comment: `The` plane? They're many…

Comment: There is an infinite number of planes containing two points. Do you want the plane that contains also the origin?

Comment: But the answer says ax+by+(b-a)z=a; a and b not both 0.

Comment: Is it possible that you're asking for **all** planes in $\mathbb R^3$ that contain these two points?

Comment: Yes for all the planes in R^3

Comment: If there were just one plane you'd get a single equation for a plane.  As there are an infinite number of planes you have an infinite number of equations.  The answer given is a formula for these infinite number equations.  For any a, b (not both zero) the result will be a possible equation.  (I think.)

Answer (score 1):

You know the general equation of the plane in $3D$:

$$ax + by + cz = d$$

In essence, the question is asking you for non-zero $(a,b,c,d)$, up to scaling, such that the above is satisfied for $P$ and $Q$. Feeding them in,:

$$ 2a - b +c = d$$
and $$a = d$$

Must be true. This implies that the planes that contain both the points are of the form
$$(a, b, b-a, a)$$

To identify them up to scaling, take the cases when $a = 0$ and $a \neq 0$ separately, to get:

$$(0, 1,1,0)$$ and $$(1, b, b-1, 1)$$

The latter for every choice of $b$. Thus, note that there are an infinite number of planes that do the job.